# Why does g++ fail on the exact same files, but on different computer

Tags: c++, g++

I'm sure I am doing something wrong but... I worked on a c++ project on one computer, with same version of Ubuntu installed, same version of g++, it compiled fine there. I put the files into a DropBox folder so that I could work on it at home, the same exact files are here, and the same exact g++ command results in errors. It is giving me several "multiple definition of '*_*' " errors.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Example error:

```
g++ -o*.C *.cpp

/tmp/ccdFZtkq.o:(.bss+0x718): multiple definition of `done'
```

Comment: Too many `same` here :) Can you post the errors and relevant code?

Comment: Random stab: might be related to different line-endings (CR/CRLF/LF)

Comment: @KingsIndian The code shouldn't be relevant...as the exact same code, in exact same files, compiles fine..I'm assuming the problem is something having to do with DropBox potentially adding some sort of versioning? maybe on files...

Comment: Paste the errors. Paste the G++ command. Paste something, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Looks like you have multiple definitions of `done'. Just a bit of humor. Post the source code, or no one can help.

Comment: This error isn't from g++.  Its from the linker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that DropBox was appending suffixes to files that I can best describe as being in "intermediate" states. DropBox also created files without the suffixes that were not in the intermediate states. I am still unsure quite what was happening, but sometime as g++ ran, it was using both the intermediate files and the non-intermediate ones, thereby running into issues of basically the same files being loaded multiple times.

I solved my problem by removing the files from the DropBox folder and recompiling, worked perfectly fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean build. Remove all the old object files and compile again.

```
rm -rf *.o
g++ -o *.C *.cpp
```

My *guess-engine* ran out of fuel. Can't give a better answer unless you show some code and info on what are the files there in your DropBox, declaration & definition of `done` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You types this into your shell:

```
g++ -o*.C *.cpp
```

But this causes your shell to generate the command. Most likely, different commands got generated in the two instances. If you take the actual command issued in the case that worked and repeat *that* command in the case that didn't work, I bet it would work.

You can find the command by going to the machine where it worked and typing this:

```
echo g++ -o*.C *.cpp
```

That will show you the command the shell generated for you. If you try that command on the other machine, I bet it will work.

(Also, your command makes no sense. What was the `-o*.C` supposed to be? Did you mean `-o something *.C`?)